# Is the following function ok to validate an email?

Tags: javascript

Just tested this function to validate an email..However,it does not validate the presence or absence of the dot in the email..Why this is happening and how can I fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isEmail(textbox){

    var reg4 =/^(\w+)@(\w+).(\w+)$/;
    if(reg4.test(textbox.value)){

            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: simply google: email validation regular expression and you will get a ton of solutions

Comment: it will at least fail `info@some-domain-with-dashes.com`, `info@mail.university.edu`, `info@localhost`, `john.smith@microsoft.com`... these are all legit email addresses.

Comment: Here is an example of RFC822 validating perl regexp which still cant handle comments: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html . So you can imagine how fun validating an email is :D

Comment: @lbu every one of which will be wrong...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's insufficient.

In particular, it doesn't handle all these (legal) variants:

1. quoted user parts, e.g. "my name"@example.com
2. Internationalised domain names (IDNs)
3. Domains with more than two labels
4. Domains with only one label (yes, those *are* legal)
5. Hyphens in domain names
6. `user@[1.2.3.4]`

Validating an e-mail address via a regexp is [*very hard*](http://ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).  See [section 3.4.1 of RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) for the formal syntax definition.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a regular expression to validate email addresses. Email addresses can include a lot of things you wouldn't imagine (like spaces), and it's more likely that the user will accidentally enter an invalid email address than an invalid one. Just check if there's an `@` then send a confirmation email if you want.

From [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378):

> There is no good (and realistic, see  [the fully RFC 822 compliant
>   regex](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)) regular
>   expression for this problem. The grammar (specified in RFC 5322) is
>   too complicated for that. Use a real parser or, better, validate by
>   trying (to send a message).

Comment: There you go: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html . However it still does not support comments in email address :D

Answer (score 1):

the dot has a meaning in a regex

use `[\.]` instead of `.`

Comment: that is the smallest of the problems with the proposed regexp

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot, which normally matches any character.

```
var reg4 =/^(\w+)@(\w+)\.(\w+)$/;
```

Comment: that is the smallest of the problems with the proposed regexp

Answer (score 1):

Escape the dot with backslash: `\.`. However, your regex would not be very good afterwards as it will not accept multiple dots in post-@ part, such as domain `foo.co.uk`.

All in all, I'd advise againts using regexes to validate emails as they tend to get [overcomplicated](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/42) ;-) Simply check for presence of @ followed by a dot, or use a similarly lenient algorithm.

Comment: it's not even strictly necessary for the domain to contain a dot.